# Finding reachable vertices

Tags: graphs

I'm trying to solve a graph problem ( it's not for homework, just to practise my skills ).

A dag $G(V,E)$ is given, where $V$ is the set of vertices and $E$ the edges. The graph is represented as an adjacency list, so $A_i$ is a set containing all the connections of $i$.

My task is to find which vertices are reachable from each vertex $v\in V$.

The solution I use has a complexity of  $O(V^3)$, with transitive closure, but i read that in a blog it can be faster, although it didn't reveal how. Could anyone tell me an other way ( with better complexity ) to solve the transitive closure problem in a dag? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $f(\cdot)$?

Comment: @JɛﬀE Sorry I edited it. I misunderstood what the blog said.

Comment: i think this is for cs@stackexchange

Comment: Check this out: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397588900321

Comment: @Kaveh isn't the problem exactly transitive closure here?

Comment: @Sasho, yes, it wasn't a good comment. What I meant is following: it can help not to think about it as the general transitive closure problem.

Comment: Perhaps a topological sort would help?

Comment: what about extracting spanning tree and graph labeling [pre,post] or dewey IDs to answer reachability questions?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an $O(VE)$ algorithm, which is substantially better than $O(V^3)$ if the graph is sparse. First do a topological sort, in time $O(V+E)$. Now work your way backwards, storing which vertices are reachable. At a vertex of outdegree $d$, this requires $O(dV)$ work, so in total you get $O(VE)$.